# Implement angular promise if statement is true, if not provide a default value

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I wish to implement an Angular promise if a user is signed in, but if not I wish to provide a default value to the backend. This currently works, but obviously it is very repetitive. Can anyone offer any guidance?

This is my code so far:

```
this.getUserDetails = TestService.get({ id: signedIn.id });
```

`this.getUserDetails` returns a JSON object which I then need to use to make a subsequent GET request, but only if the user is signed in.

```
 // this is executed if user not signed in
if(!signedIn.Id){
 controller.test_type = "Whatever"

   TestService.query({test_type: controller.test_type}, function (prices) {
       this.test = prices.prices;
    }).$promise; 
}

//executed if user is signed in, but must wait for backend to return data first

else{
    this.getUserDetails.$promise.then(function(data){ 
    TestService.query({test_type: data.test_type}, function (prices) {
        this.test = prices.prices;
    }).$promise; 
}
```

Please let me know if any further details are required.

Thanks

Comment: Could you take a look at the code snippet as there is something wrong with it. You  have an `else` that is disconnected from the if because Testservice.query is in the way

Comment: cheers Simon, well spotted. that was an error on my behalf when copying the code over, as I deleted a lot of code that was unneccessary for this question.

Comment: I don't really understand your objective nor do I know much about $promise (compared to $q), but you could simply return a resolved promise in the one case, and a promise that resolves later otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about chaining and nesting the calls like this:

```
function check(){
  if(signedIn){
    return this.getUserDetails.$promise
  }else{
    return $q.when(controller)  
  }
};

check().then(function(data){
    TestService.query({test_type: data.test_type}, function (prices) {
        this.test = prices.prices;
    });
});
```